# SQL Count on large table using multiple joins - mysql speed tip?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, count

Is there anyway I can improve on this query to have better performance?

```
SELECT count(stories.id), count(distinct table_1.table_2_id), count(distinct table_1.id)
FROM stories
    INNER JOIN table_1 ON (table_1.id = stories.table_1_id)
    INNER JOIN table_2 ON (table_2.id = table_1.table_2_id)
    INNER JOIN table_3 ON (table_3.id = table_2.table_3_id)
    INNER JOIN table_4 ON (table_4.id = table_3.table_4_id)
    INNER JOIN table_5 ON (table_5.id = table_4.table_5_id)
WHERE stories.id in (select s2.id
                    from stories s2
                    where s2.published_at between '2015-01-01' and '2020-02-21'
                    and s2.deleted = false
                    )
```

I currently need this info, (the counts) for a dashboard total.

All tables involved are `Inno DB`, I have indexes on all ids being joined.
My stories table currently has over 15M records, and growing.

What is the best approach, in terms of scalability, to deal with a situation like this?

Comment: You are only using data from `stories` and `table_1` why all the other JOINS?

Comment: Why the sub select couldn't you just do `WHERE stories.published_at between '2015-01-01' and '2020-02-21' AND stories.deleted = false`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi, for the first question, I need the other tables, because there must be an association to all of them, for the record to be `valuable` to my dashboard. as for the sub select, I got the query to execute faster using it like that. I was doing it that way, like you said.

Comment: @RiggsFolly *You are only using data from stories and table_1 why all the other JOINS?* INNER JOINs may decrease amounts (counting only those records which have related records).

Comment: yes, exaclty @Akina

Comment: Right, but I thought I should check, as not everyone here uses code because there is a good reason, sometimes it's what they copied from somewhere else and didnt bother to fully understand ? @Akina

Comment: Sure, no problem @RiggsFolly! Thanks for your time analyzing it

Comment: Is ID unique on the story table?

Comment: yes, they are unique @Error_2646

Comment: No. It was just plain inattention. `AND s2.deleted = false` is equal to `AND NOT s2.deleted` which makes the same anount of operations. This would be true for comparign with TRUE.

Comment: by using EXISTS instead of IN, I've got a better response time, altough, my results changed, anyone knows why?

Comment: Why include table_3/4/5 -- You don't seem to use them??  Removing them will speed up the query significantly.

Comment: it was explained above @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need plenty of the appropriate indexes.

1. One index you need which is easy to overlook is

   ```
   CREATE INDEX stories_deleted_published_at ON stories(deleted, published_at);
   ```
2. If it were not for filtering only some story records, you could separate the count of story.id to

   ```
   SELECT count(*) from stories;
   ```

   Databases often keep count of how many records are in a table, and can optimize this to a very quick answer.  However, that does not apply in this case.
3. I am assuming every `id` field is a primary key.  If you already prevent orphans in your database, then the last join becomes a test if `table_4.table_5_id` is NULL.  If so you could try:

   ```
   SELECT count(stories.id), count(distinct table_1.table_2_id), count(distinct table_1.id)
   FROM stories
       INNER JOIN table_1 ON (table_1.id = stories.table_1_id)
       INNER JOIN table_2 ON (table_2.id = table_1.table_2_id)
       INNER JOIN table_3 ON (table_3.id = table_2.table_3_id)
       INNER JOIN table_4 ON (table_4.id = table_3.table_4_id)
                             AND table_4.table_5_id IS NOT NULL
   WHERE stories.id in (select s2.id
                   from stories s2
                   where s2.published_at between '2015-01-01' and '2020-02-21'
                   and s2.deleted = false
                   )
   ```
4. You said it was slower when the subquery is replaced with `stories.published_at between '2015-01-01' and '2020-02-21' and stories.deleted = false`.  Just to try it, you could have this in the joins clause.  That might be a hint to the optimizer to filter the records while doing the join instead of filtering the results after the join is done.

   ```
   SELECT count(stories.id), count(distinct table_1.table_2_id), count(distinct table_1.id)
   FROM stories
       INNER JOIN table_1 ON (table_1.id = stories.table_1_id)
                             AND stories.published_at between '2015-01-01' and '2020-02-21'
                             AND stories.deleted = false
       INNER JOIN table_2 ON (table_2.id = table_1.table_2_id)
       INNER JOIN table_3 ON (table_3.id = table_2.table_3_id)
       INNER JOIN table_4 ON (table_4.id = table_3.table_4_id)
                             AND table_4.table_5_id IS NOT NULL
   ```

Comment: The distinct count is a very slow operation.  The database has to sort the results and count unique ones.  I assume you need the answer, so there is no avoiding it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response.  Marlin
I tried, both number 3, and number 4, after creating the index.
for number 3, I got the results in: 52,33 sec
for number 4, I got the results in: 49.17 sec

Comment: InnoDB does not keep a count of records, not even in the simplest of cases.

Comment: `ON` clauses are equivalent to `WHERE` clauses for `JOIN`.  (They are different for `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`.)  For human readability, `ON` should say how the tables 'relate' and `WHERE` should specify filtering.

Comment: @RickJames "`ON` clauses are equivalent to `WHERE`", you are correct in terms of results.  However, the OP got a time improvement moving the condition to the `ON` clause.  Yes, a perfect optimizer would do these the same and fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  count(*),
        count(distinct table_1.table_2_id),
        count(distinct table_1.id)
    FROM stories AS s
    JOIN table_1 ON (table_1.id = stories.table_1_id)
    JOIN table_2 ON (table_2.id = table_1.table_2_id)
    WHERE s.published_at >= '2015-01-01'
      AND s.published_at  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 3 WEEK
      AND s.deleted = FALSE
      AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM table_3 ON (table_3.id = table_2.table_3_id)
                     JOIN table_4 ON (table_4.id = table_3.table_4_id)
                     JOIN table_5 ON (table_5.id = table_4.table_5_id) );
```

Notes:

- Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(x)` unless you need to check `x` for NULLness.
- `EXISTS` is faster than `JOINing` because it stops as soon as one row is found.
- There is no need to do the full `JOIN`; it is canceled out by `DISTINCT`.
- `stories` needs `INDEX(deleted, published_at, table_2_id, id)` -- in that order.  (This makes it "covering".)

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Do you even need that `EXISTS()` clause?